# Работа с пакетным менеджером YARN

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vue3, yarn

Всех приветствую. Дали посмотреть/пощупать проект, написан на vue и в качестве пакетного менеджера используется YARN. При работе с пакетным менеджером NPM при команде в терминале NPM RUN SERVE запускается проект на localhost.
Как можно запустить проект через  команду yarn?

Answer (score 0):

`yarn run serve` или `yarn serve`. Об этом написано в документации (всегда читайте документацию):

- v1: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/
- v2: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/run